# Using json2typescript - ignores the custom names for child classes

Tags: json, angular

I am using https://github.com/dhlab-basel/json2typescript  to deserialize this rather 'criptic' json response into Typescripts classes

```
{
    "xp": 0,
    "xt": 34000,
    "dl": 
    [
        {
            "p05": 2000.0000000000002  
        },
        {
            "p05": 400.0000000000002
        }
    ],
}
```

I said criptic because we need to translate this variables into something more 'human'
(Example, p05 is Price whitout Taxes, or pWoTaxes for better understanding of the code)
I am using two classes and following along the json2typescript converter example:

Parent:

```
@JsonObject
export class TheParentClass{
  @JsonProperty("xp", Number) priceX: number= undefined;
  @JsonProperty("xt", Number) externalThing: number= undefined;

  // As shown with the Cities example
  //  @JsonProperty("cities", [City]) cities: City[] = undefined;
  @JsonProperty("dl", [TheChildClass]) lineDetail: TheChildClass[] = undefined;

}
```

And the ChildClass:

```
@JsonObject
export class TheChildClass{
  @JsonProperty("p05", Number) someBetterNameForThis: number= undefined;
}
```

Because dl is actually an array of objects

When I run this code with the json response provided, I get this error:

```
Error: Fatal error in JsonConvert. Failed to map the JSON object to the JavaScript class "Order" because of a type error.

Class property: 
    lineDetail

Expected type: 
    [TheChildClass]

JSON property: 
    dl

JSON type: 
    [object]
```

So I changed my definition to:

```
@JsonProperty("dl", [Object]) lineDetail: TheChildClass[] = undefined;
```

And it worked. But then the TheParentClass looses all custom named properties for TheChildClass, rendering all my component code useless.

- TheParentClass.lineDetail[0].someBetterNameForThis returns undefined
- TheParentClass.lineDetail[0].p05 still returns the correct value

At this moment it tought TheChildClass maybe wasn't being reached by the parent because the change i did when I tried to get it as [Object] from the json, so I put some faulty code on TheChildClass just to see what happens...
Surprise, when trying to deserialize the Parent, the error was raised, so TheChildClass was being correctly processed, but it totally ignores the names i am defining for the p05 variable. This is not happening fir the custom names I've created for the actual Parent class names.

Why wouldn't then get the new name I created for the p05 variable?

Comment: `lineDetail:[TheChildClass]` is invalid type. Make sure you configured TS properly https://github.com/dhlab-basel/json2typescript#requirements . I'd suggest to ask in repo issues instead, because the question is specific to the library - and not a popular one.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry about that.